# Lwjgl 3, How to get OpenGL context current in the current thread?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am using OpenGL in LWJGL 3 and I get the following error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no OpenGL context current in the current thread.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.getCapabilities(GL.java:157)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.getInstance(GL11.java:1390)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearColor(GL11.java:1842)
    at com.base.engine.RenderUtil.initGraphics(RenderUtil.java:13)
    at com.base.engine.Main.<init>(Main.java:14)
    at com.base.engine.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

This is the RenderUtil class where initGraphics is called from the constructor of my main class. I have also tried to call initGraphics after creating a window with GLFW which has also generated a similar error message.

```
    package com.base.engine;
    
    import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
    import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
    
    public class RenderUtil {
    
        public static void clearScreen() {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
    
        public static void initGraphics() {
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    
            glFrontFace(GL_CW);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    
            glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
        }
    }
```

Also, I am not using multithreading. To create a window I call the method `Window.createWindow(1366, 768, "Test");` from my main method.
```
private static Long window;

```
    public static String createWindow(int width, int height, String title) {
        if (GLFW.glfwInit() == 0) {
            return "GLFW failed to initialise.";
        }

        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
        window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title,
                GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), 0);

        if (window == null) {
            GLFW.glfwTerminate();
            return "Failed to create window.";
        }

        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        return "GLFW has established a window.";
    }
```

```
I have tried putting `RenderUtil.initGraphics();` two different position in my main method, both resulting in errors.

        private boolean isRunning = false;
        private Game game;
    

        // This is the constructor
        public Main() {
            // Pos 1 - RenderUtil.initGraphics();
            isRunning = false;
            game = new Game();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(Window.createWindow(1366, 768, "Test"));
            // Pos 2 - RenderUtil.initGraphics();
            Main game = new Main();
            game.start();
        }
```

Comment: It should already be current unless you created your context in a different thread. Nevertheless, each window system has its own `...MakeCurrent` function to do this. LWJGL is no different, [`GLContext.makeCurrent (long)`](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GLContext.html#makeCurrent(long)) wraps the platform specific stuff.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your window and context?

Comment: @Jack: seeing your `main` would be interesting, too.

Comment: Ok, I added that in above.

Answer (score 15):

Add a call to `GLContext.createFromCurrent()` at the end of the `createWindow` method.

This method is needed to set the context used by the LWJGL GL** classes under the hood.

**EDIT:**

Since the latest nightly (3.0.0b #11) this no longer works, as the `GLContext` class no more exists. Instead, add `GL.createCapabilities()` at the end of the `createWindow` method.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is 4 years old but if someone of you still needs a solution here you go:

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

public class Main {
private static long window = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(!GLFW.glfwInit()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot initialize OPenGL");
    }

    window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(1024, 764, "Ya yeet", 0, 0);
    if(0 == window) {
        GLFW.glfwTerminate();
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create window");
    }

    GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();

    String glVersion = GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION);
    System.out.println(glVersion);
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To init and use LWJGL 3 you need to do next (code in Kotlin):

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL


class VersionInfo {

    var window: Long = NULL

    fun run() {
        initGl()

        // use openGL
        val glVersion = GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION)
        println("GL version: $glVersion")
    }

    private fun initGl() {
        // check GLFW
        if (!GLFW.glfwInit()) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Can not initialize GLFW")
        }
        // create window
        window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(1024, 764, "glfw", NULL, NULL)
        // check window
        if (NULL == window) {
            GLFW.glfwTerminate()
            throw IllegalStateException("Can not create new GLFW window")
        }
        // make GL context in the current thread
        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)
        // create capabilities
        GL.createCapabilities()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            VersionInfo().run()
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, please, see official get-started guide: http://www.lwjgl.org/guide 
Or Wiki: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki

Comment: That is not helpful, the official example gives the same error for me. It isn't compilable even with latest lwjgl (3.0.0a build 1)...

Comment: @user2084865 The website already uses the new API of the beta version, see the edit of [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27678762/4521040).

Comment: Yep, that solved it for me. Tried it already, but anyways, thanks ;-)

Comment: The original post has a "java" tag, so why is your useless answer in Kotlin?