# Lwjgl installation errors

Tags: java, installation, lwjgl

I am trying to get LWJGL to work on my mac (OS X Yosemite 10.10.3) and I installed it following all the tutorials. Every time I load in the test code from [this](http://www.lwjgl.org/guide) web site it never works. Its always this line:

GL.createCapabilities();

The method createCapabilities(boolean) in the type GL is not applicable for the arguments ()

I tried putting true and false in as arguments, however they both crashed it:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no OpenGL context current in the current thread.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.getCapabilities(GL.java:164)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.getInstance(GL11.java:1388)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearColor(GL11.java:1828)
    at Game.loop(Game.java:97)
    at Game.run(Game.java:26)
    at Game.main(Game.java:113)

I also have tried changing it to GL.getCapabilities(); but it doesn't work either.

I don't know if I forgot to load something or what, but could someone please help me.

Comment: Try searching for the exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659729/lwjgl-3-how-to-get-opengl-context-current-in-the-current-thread/27678762#27678762

Comment: Omg you don't know how long this has taken to work, thank you so much!